# npm install express --ejs . not creating folder structure

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, express-generator

I am trying to create node js template using express --ejs .

I have create folder in "C:\MEAN_Stack"
then open power shell as admin 
run command npm install express-generator -g
then go to my app folder
then run the command **npm install express --ejs .** but this command just create the node_modules folder not other folder.
[image]

[image]
I am referring the [this article](https://github.com/hwz/chirp/tree/master/module-3)

Answer (score 1):

When you want to create a project scaffolding with express, you need to execute:

```
express --ejs .
```

`npm` is used to install the express generator (and after to install dependencies with `npm install`).

Comment: i tried this also but i got the error
express : The term 'express' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ express --ejs .
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (express:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: first you need to install the express generator with `npm install -g generator-express`, the `-g` option is to install the generator in global mode (accessible from anywhere). Then you can run `express --ejs .`

Comment: i forgot to inform that i have already install the express generator

Answer (score 0):

Install express-generator first :

```
npm install express-generator -g
```

Then create your app with :

```
express nameofapp
```